# How to install Python 3.3 (not 3.4) on OS X with Homebrew?

Tags: python, django, macos, python-3.x, homebrew

If you install python3 through Homebrew it installs the latest version by default, which I did. But I want 3.3 instead of 3.4. How can I replace it with 3.3 specifically using Homebrew? I want to try Django with Python 3 but I'm just learning Django so I want to use the latest stable version, currently 1.6, which is compatible with up to Python 3.3. I want to use it with Python 3, so it has to be 3.3. Django 1.7 is Py3.4 compatible but I don't want to mess with that 'til it's stable... on OS X 10.8.5

Comment: The latest OS X comes with python 3.3.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: Are you sure Django 1.6 *won't* work with Python 3.4, at least well enough to play around with it?

Comment: @chepner, no I'm not; just going by what it says officially on djangoproject.com.

Comment: @RafaelBarros I should have mentioned I have OS X 10.8.5, which comes with Python 2.7...

Comment: @RafaelBarros: 10.9.4 does not include python 3. Unless you're talking about the public beta?

Comment: @sharth 10.9.3 has python 3.3.3 when you type python3 on the terminal. OSX 10.9.4 updated it to 3.4.0

Comment: @RafaelBarros: 10.9.4 does not include any version of Python 3. You have presumably installed an external version but if you look in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ you'll see nothing later than 2.7

Comment: Consider using a virtualenv (or conda env) to install multiple versions of python at the same time and easily switch between them. I don't have a link handy, but Google should easily find something

Answer (score 12):

Here are some elements that you can piece together from the [homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ).

1. [Can I edit formulae myself?](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ#can-i-edit-formulae-myself) - yes.

   ```
   brew edit python3
   ```
2. look for the `url` and change it to the ftp link to the `3.3` ([`3.3.6`](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.6/)) archive.
3. download the archive locally and compute the checksum with `shasum`.
4. save the file as `python33.rb` and install with `brew install --debug python33.rb`.

Passing the `--debug` flag will help you in case some steps are not working properly (e.g. in the latest formula, removing the `2to3` binary was a problem), you may just try to revert [this change](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commit/a46be6e4c01b00d602f6ffb32bc2114f9eafee1d#diff-0922b0fcac5fb36b7d2e5bc1156a4eaf) as python3.3 does not have `ensurepip` bootstrap module.

You can find the formula I used here: [python 3.3.5](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/blob/032806d05cbdd2077f3e63f5e60355223ad2a369/Library/Formula/python3.rb)

Comment: If you download the package manually and `shasum` it, you can copy + paste that output into the `sha256` variable when you're `brew edit python3`. This way you can `brew install python3` like normal

Comment: gist link is broken.