# Brew - Install python3.3

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

I want install the specific 3.3 version of python.

I have tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/2139691
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207883/125507

`brew versions` is not longer supported.

`brew search python3` does not show python3.X versions.

`brew tap homebrew/versions` does not work neither.

How can I install python3.3 in macosx using `brew` and I don't want to use `pyenv`.

Comment: If using `homebrew` is not critical, you can try [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer).

Comment: @fjarri I have updated the question pointing that pyenv is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26522217/2139691)

First uninstall python3

```
brew uninstall python3
```

Download this formula
https://gist.github.com/booleangate/8f0bb23fdd53d699f763f0959c506049

Then go to directory where formula was downloaded and intro into terminal

```
brew install --debug python33.rb
```

From now on, if you want run this version of python you must type on terminal:

```
07:03:17 $ python3.3 
Python 3.3.6 (default, Jan 26 2016, 06:48:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2+2                 
4
>>> 3*3==9
True
>>>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The gist must be edited to replace the 3 occurrences of `sha1` with `Formula.sha256` or else you get an error.

Comment: I think it's probably a better option to install the binary directly from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/ . I was able to install python3.5.4 on Mac El Capitan in this way. This way you get python directly from the source, rather than installing software via formulas found on gist.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead.

Comment: @TheMatt I suggest to install pyenv.

Comment: I was going to fix the link but the formula doesn't work anymore anyway.  Use pyenv instead.